# Correct placement for 1,200 lb pizza oven on wooden box I built

Tags: wood, framing, studs, engineering

I am not much of a DIY-er, but I decided I wanted to try and make a stand for a 1,200 lb pizza oven I wanted to buy. I built a box out of 4x4's, and wrapped it in 5/8" OSB.

The dimensions of the surface of the box are 48"x48", and the pizza oven is 40"x40". The problem I'm dealing with now is that if the pizza oven is centered on the surface, most of the 4x4 beams around the perimeter aren't directly under the oven, due to the 4" inset all the way around.

So given the design in the picture where there are two center vertical pillars in the back two rows, but not in the first row, I'm wondering if I need to either scoot the pizza oven all the way to the front, or else all the way to the back. Or will it work fine being centered? Maybe I am just being overly nervous, but I want this to last, and as I said, this is my first rodeo with framing.

[image: 8 vertical 4x4 beams]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It will be fine in terms of the weight... the 4x4s in the center will easily handle the load.  I'm a bit concerned about the OSB though.  Personally if it isn't too late I'd really suggest 3/4" CDX plywood.  But if it's too late don't lose sleep over it, just a long shot.

Comment: I'd agree on the OSB; composites tend to distort over time. Plywood would be much better, especially given how much effort you've put into this.

Comment: Agree that plywood is preferable to OSB, but if you're sticking with the OSB, paint/varnish the heck out of it for weather resistance. My only other comment is that I hope you have lots of screws/nails in the OSB that makes up the side panels... those are very important for shear. (Which is to say, preventing the whole box from collapsing forward or backward.)

Comment: To insuate and prevent fire, I would put a sheet of ss steel or coriander (not the spice) or something on top of the box.

Comment: @PaulBinCT2 Thanks for the feedback. So if I went with the 3/4" CDX plywood on top, would it not matter where I positioned the oven? Centered, front flush, or back flush? If I decide not to replace the top board, should I slide it to the back to make sure it is sitting on the strongest 4x4's?

Comment: @Lizza It would matter a bit less, but it's more of a durability issue.  I don't think you have to worry much about the placement.